# How do I toggle a knockout foreach div individually without adding more html?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I used the foreach method to create markup foreach item in an observable array to create a treeview.
output example

category name1
     content
     content
category name 2
     content
     content

when I click on the category name I want just its content to show/hide, currently when I click on the category name it shows and hides all the categories.

```
 var reportFilters = [
        { Text: "Campaign", Value: primaryCategories.Campaign },
        { Text: "Team", Value: primaryCategories.Team },
        { Text: "Agent", Value: primaryCategories.Agent },
        { Text: "List", Value: primaryCategories.List },
        { Text: "Inbound", Value: primaryCategories.Inbound },
        { Text: "Daily", Value: primaryCategories.Daily },
        { Text: "Services", Value: primaryCategories.Services },
        { Text: "Occupancy", Value: primaryCategories.Occupancy },
        { Text: "Data", Value: primaryCategories.Data }
    ];


  self.showCategory = ko.observable(false);      
    self.toggleVisibility = function (report) {
        var categoryName = report.PrimaryReportCategory;
        var categoryContent = report.ID;
        if (categoryName == categoryContent ) {
            self.showCategory(!self.showCategory());
        };
    }
  <div class="report-category-treeview"  data-bind="foreach: $root.categories, mCustomScrollBar:true">
            <ul class="column-list" >
                <li class="report-category-heading" data-bind="click: $root.toggleVisibility"><span class="margin-top10" ><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> <span class="report-category-name" data-bind="text: categoryName"></span></span></li>
                <li id="panel" class="report-category-container" data-bind="foreach: reports, visible: $root.showCategory">
                    <div class="column-list-item" data-bind="click: $root.report_click, css: { 'selected': typeof $root.selectedReport() != 'undefined' && $data == $root.selectedReport() }">
                        <span class="column-list-text" data-bind="text: ReportName"></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> currently, when I click on the category name, it shows and hides all the
>   categories.

It's because `showCategory` is your single observable responsible for showing\hiding. What you really want is one show\hide observable *per category*.

I'm not sure how your entire data model looks like, but since you specifically asked about `categories`, then you should create a `category` view model, and probably some container view model, which I'll name here `master`:

```
var categoryVM = function (name) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleVisibility = function () {
        self.isVisible(!self.isVisible());
    }
    // ... add here your other observables ...
}

// name 'masterVM' whatever you like
var masterVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ko.observables([]);
    // ... probably add here other observables, e.g. 'reports' ...
    self.init = function (rawCategories) {
        rawCategories.forEach(function (item) {
            categories.push(new categoryVM(item.name)); // replace 'name' with your property
        }
    }
}

var master = new masterVM();
master.init(getCategories()); // pass in your categories from wherever they come from
ko.applyBindings(master);
```

Then, in your html, this would be your outer `foreach`:

```
<div class="report-category-treeview" data-bind="foreach: categories ... />
```

and your `li`s (for brevity, I'm ommiting nested tags under your `li`s):

```
<li class="report-category-heading" 
    data-bind="click: toggleVisibility">
<li id="panel" class="report-category-container" 
    data-bind="foreach: $root.reports, visible: isVisible">
```